# How to Validate Windows form

Tags: c#, .net

How to validate a registration form? Currently, I am working on a project and it has many  textboxes few radio buttons and checkboxes and I need to validate each textbox in which few textbox are mandatory and few can be empty but if user enters text on those empty textboxes it should validate those inputs. Currently, I am using regular expression with nested if else statement but it is very time consuming and I am getting confused with so many if else statement.

```
if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty) {
    Regex emp1=new Regex("^[a-z-A-Z]+$");
    if(emp1.IsMatch(textBox1.Text)) {
        if (textBox2.Text != string.Empty) {
            Regex emp2 = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");
            if(emp2.IsMatch(textBox2.Text)) {
                int a = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("characters not allowed");
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("pls enter age");
        }                       
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("no. are not allowed ");
    }
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("pls enter name");
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: ugly code sample please use the formatting within `SO` nobody wants to scroll though this mess

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like `if` statements...

Comment: `Currently, I am using regular expression with nested if else statement but it is very time consuming and I am getting confused with so many if else statement.` - yes, let's all make fun of him for how unreadable his nested if statements are. I think he's already discovered the problem with this, and apparently wants help doing it the right way.

Comment: If it works, I don't think you should change it. Maybe it is quite confusing, but it may help if you comment your } brackets. For instance:
`if(a>b) { do things and more if } //if(a>b)`
So, even if you have a lot of this statements you always know what are referring to.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `return false`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code is working but asking for code review. Such questions should be asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use return after every check.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("pls enter name");
    textBox1.Focus();
    return;
}

Regex emp1=new Regex("^[a-z-A-Z]+$");
if (!emp1.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("no. are not allowed ");
    return;
}
```

etc.

If you don't like spreading returns into your code you can use `else if`. For such checks I personally favor using returns right after the message.

Comment: Please no, don't encourage multiple exit points from a method. It makes said method much harder to debug/maintain.

Comment: Depends on how many specific actions one wants to do after a failed check. The problem with if else approach in this case can be that you can't always do all the validation steps in one expression to be usable inside the if statement. In the case he has shown he had to construct a Regex first. It can be rewritten to an expression but thats not always possible.

Comment: @CraigW. No, If all the exit points are at the top of the method(typically validations) itself there is nothing wrong. Keeps code readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `else if` statements like so:

```
string message = null;
TextBox focusMe = null;

if (failure1)
{
    message = "message1";
}
else if (failure2)
{
    message = "message2";
}
else if (failure3)
{
    message = "message3";
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    MessageBox.Show(message);

    if (focusMe != null) focusMe.Focus();
}
```

I'm a fan of a single `return`, so this is my preferred style. Also, you can easily modify this to check for multiple error conditions by replacing the `else if`'s with `if`'s, and adding the errors to a list.

Comment: +1 for not having returns scattered throughout the code.

Comment: Depends if you can always write your failure condition as one expression. You wouldn't want to calculate n failure variables in front.

Comment: @BlueM you could always use an `&&` in the failure condition, nest another level of `if`'s, or factor out something complex to a separate function. It comes down to what is most readable.